# How to start an embedded instance of gridgain in java

Tags: testing, integration, gridgain

Is there a way to start an embedded instance of Gridgain without having to run it manually? We are trying to write integration test but I don't see any easy way to start an instance in memory :) as a embedded instance

Answer (score 0):

You can start as many embedded instances of GridGain as you like in your application by calling various `GridGain.start(...)` methods, as it is done in provided examples. Those methods will return you an instance of the started `Grid`.

For example, calling `GridGain.start(String pathToXml)` method is essentially equivalent to running `ggstart.{bat|sh}` script with the same configuration file (refer to javadoc for details).

You can also create an instance of `GridCofiguration` programmatically and use the `GridGain.start(GridConfiguration cfg)` method if you do not want to use xml/spring dependencies for some reason.